# keeping track of user in oauth 2.0 authorization flow

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am having trouble understanding how to use oauth 2.0 with users.

I have an app that has users and companies (that users belong to).  I want a user to authorize a third party app with their company or them.

I have stored my apps `client_id`, `secret` and `redirect_url` for that third party app.

The user is signed in to the app on the front end and has a button they can click to authorize with the third party app.  This will redirect them to the third party website with the `client_id` and `redirect_url`.  Once the user signs in to that site and has authenticated with the third party it will send a grant token to the `redirect_url` on my server.

This is where I am having problems.  At this point on the server I have received a code that I can then use to get the token.  But what the server does not know at this point is who the user was that started the flow.  This means once I get the token I do not know who to associate the token with (either user or company).

How can I track which user is authenticating through the oauth 2.0 flow.

This is for sites like Quickbooks, Zoho, Facebook, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone stumbles onto this question in the future.

I have a React Front End hosted seperatly than my backend API server.

I was setting the redirect_url to go to an endpoint on the backend server which was an unauthenticated endpoint and where my problem was.

Now the user will go to the authorization url link on the third party.  Once they authorize the redirect url will send them to an authenticated endpoint on my frontend react app where they will be signed in already.  This page will pull the code from the url and send it back to the server like any other data request which is made by the user.  Now on the server I have the code which I can process to get the token and I also now have the user and company to associate it with.

This also make so much more sense because I can have a nice display page showing the user what is happening and when they have been connected.